# Xcode 5.01 and Cordova 2.9 archive issues

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, cordova

I have been developing my app on top of the Cordova 2.9 framework and it builds fine on the iPhone simulator and also builds fine on my devices. When I try to "archive" it to submit to the app store it throws these errors:

[image]

I don't understand why it builds and runs fine but won't archive for the store. I also tried to archive Cordova 2.9 right out of the box so to speak without any of my files in it and it still fails with these errors. Does anyone know how to fix these errors?

I have tried things like
Change "Build Active Architecture Only" to "YES"

Go to project settings and Build Tab.
Search for "Other Linker Flags"
Double click on the linker flags for Release and Change ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/libCordova.a to ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/libCordova.a
Do the same for Debug Clean and build archive again

Those haven't worked.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you upload a higher resolution screenshot? This one isn't legible.

Comment: @Andrew sure...i will go to upload

Comment: @Andrew this is enough for you..